# Short story about wired/smart sidewalks in a dystopian future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The sidewalks are wired and people must wear smart shoes which communicate with the ground at all times, so they can be tracked by the government. The protagonist ultimately rebels by removing his shoes and walking barefoot, which on these sidewalks is violently painful.

I remember reading it a few years ago. Google has been no help in finding the title, just red herrings.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: interesting how this "guide" link causes "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" erro in Vivaldi/Chromium browser